# Sql Update Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got MySQL update query like this :

```
"INSERT INTO $tbl_name
(status, name, ...)
VALUES
('$status', '$name'...)
ON duplicate KEY UPDATE
status=values(status), name=values(name)...
";
```

It have a lot of table columns so to keep it short I`ll get right to the issue:

Instead of updating the current table row it duplicates it with a new ID.

Note : There are unique fields in the row. Any ideas what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is your key an auto number field?

Comment: What are the unique keys on the table?  `on duplicate key update` uses this information to determine what is a duplicate.

Comment: The ID key is auto inc number. Also there are 3 unique keys :/ The db is not desinged by me I`m supoused to edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check existence before doing any Insert/Update

```
IF (SELECT 1 = 1 FROM Table WHERE Key=...) THEN
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table Set status=values(status), name=values(name)... WHERE Key=...;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table (FieldValue) VALUES('');
END;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

?

Comment: Becouse the functionality of the page is required to be able to insert or update/edit already insrted info (User General Info)